# How to use regex expression to match exact words at the start of a column name?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am making a list of column names from a pandas dataframe 'df' whose name starts with string_1.

```
string_1 = "some string"
lookupcol = [col for col in df.columns if string_1 in col]
```

But the above code is also returning column names which contains string_1.

So my typical output looks like this.

```
['some string 1990', 'have some string', 'some string 1991']
```

I want to use a regex expression, so that result include only those column names which starts with  'some string'.

Output should be like this:

```
['some string 1990', 'some string 1991']
```

Comment: If it is always fixed, you can do something like: `lookupcol = [col for col in df.columns if string_1  == col[:len(string_1)]]`

Comment: `df.columns.str.startswith(string_1)`